# Cannot change/replace values of a global hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, hash, global-variables

I'm coding a simple text game to learn ruby. The hash has to be a global variable since I have to access it in other functions (There may be other solutions, but I could find this one). I'm trying to change values of hash elements. The function below basically increases the current price by 10%, and in its current form correctly changes the values and outputs them but fails to write them to the original hash.

```
$stocks = {"DOHOL" => 10, "GOZDE" => 5, "KONYA" => 20}

def margin
  puts "New values:\n "
  $stocks.each do|key, value|
    percent = (value.to_i / 10) + 1
    change = rand(percent)
    value += change
    puts "#{key}: #{value} USD"
  end
end
```

I surely wish that I could make it to randomly decrease/increase the price by 10% but this is another challenge, I would like to solve by myself, so please do not comment on that one. More importantly, I have another question about hashes. Is there an obligation to use key and value, because googling tutorials, I have seen people using pairs like "name, value" or "person, name" instead of "key, value" without defining anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `each` method from a hash will give you two things to work with in the block. It's up to you how you name those things and you define the names between the ||'s.

The new values have to be explicitly stored in the hash before the end of the block:

```
$stocks[key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd try to lose the global variable as they're in general more pain than they're worth. Basically because the process of debugging becomes really painful especially when you're changing the value off it on several places, here are some [good alternatives](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

That aside, I think what you want to do is assign a different value to the values in side your Hash. You can achieve this as follows:

```
    def margin(hash)
      hash.each do |stock, value|
        hash[stock] = random_stock_increase(value)
      end
    end

    def random_stock_increase(value)
      increase = rand((value.to_i / 10) + 1)
      value + increase
    end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a very nice example of code, which made me understand how easy it is to get things done with functions. Since I am noob, I cannot think of such an aesthetic code, yet. I read the link you recommended but neither the program I code, nor I am in a position to benefit from that wiki:) But at least now I see that I don't know how to pass a variable from one method to the other, that's why I use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're free to call the keys and values in iterator as you want. But here's could be misunderstanding of what is a key and what is a value in your hash. That's why it's rare to use another names for key and value (even I never haven't seen this one).

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second question, you can use whatever you want as "key" and "value".  These are local variables within the scope of the each loop.  However, whatever labels you provide will corresponds to the "key" and "value" of the hash as you iterate.  You should probably choose names that make sense for your loop.

```
stocks = {"DOHOL" => 10, "GOZDE" => 5, "KONYA" => 20}
stocks.each do |name, price|
  stocks[name] = price * 2
end
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
stocks = {"DOHOL" => 10, "GOZDE" => 5, "KONYA" => 20}
stocks.each do |pirate, ninja|
  stocks[pirate] = ninja * 2
end
```

but the first is certainly more understandable.